# Java Swing - Background of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to design a `JPanel` which should have the color coding as shown in the following diagram:

[image]
<sub>(source: [compendiumblog.com](http://local.content.compendiumblog.com/uploads/user/b8bbc9ab-67b1-4a8e-ac5c-5811daa967bd/ec324f27-588d-454b-a857-82d79d6acad6/survey-template.gif))</sub>

How can I code the colors of a `JPanel`. What I think is that add 5 `JPanel`s (for 5 blocks shown above) on a main JPanel. Set the `background` of each JPanel to `light Gray`.

But then how can I achieve the dark color lines as shown in the diagram.

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: which layout are you using for the panel? Are these controls static or dynamically added at runtime?

Comment: Controls are static. I don't think layout of the panel is related to color coding of the panel (correct me if I am wrong)...

Answer (score 3):

Try using a JTable and then alternating the colors of the row. This way you can write a generic JComponent (AlternatingColorTable) and use it just like a regular JTable in those 4 panels.

Something like this maybe:

```
public class AlternatingColorTable extends JTable {

public AlternatingColorTable () {
    super();
}

public AlternatingColorTable(TableModel tableModel) {
    super(tableModel);
}

/** Extends the renderer to alternate row colors */
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
    Component returnComp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);

    Color alternateColor = Color.GRAY;
    Color mainColor = Color.DARK_GRAY;

    if (!returnComp.getBackground().equals(getSelectionBackground())) {
        Color background = (row % 2 == 0 ? alternateColor : mainColor );
        returnComp.setBackground(background);
        background = null;
    }
    return returnComp;
}
```

}

Comment: +1 Well, to me, the background color shifting is to be done in the TableCellRenderer, but it's only a matter of choice

Comment: I think the prepareRenderer() method is the perfect place for this since you only need to do it in one place. Otherwise you need a custom renderer for the String column and the RadioButton columns. See http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/ for my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Just make each of the colored bars themselves panels with a different background color. Don't forget to make the panels explicitly opaque with setOpaque(true) - panels are transparent by default transparent in most look and feels.

A note on aesthetics; I would start with the first line in each group shaded differently.